# How do I get my code to read all tables when scraping a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am super new to python, This website has helped me out so much during the semester and I am hoping you guys could help me again.

I need to scrape tables from https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/.

Those tables are most actives, gainers, and losers.

Now I was able to make this code work for me

```
     import requests
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

     url = 'http://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/index.html'
     response = requests.get(url)
     html = response.content

     soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

     all_stock = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'wsod_hotStocks'})

     table = all_stock.find('table',attrs={'class':'wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt'  })

     for row in table.findAll('tr'):
         for cell in row.findAll('td'):
                 print(cell.text)
```

but that only gets me the most active table, I am not sure what I need to do to make my code get the other 2 tables that are on the website.

I would appreciate any insight on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

I don't know if I have to create code to scrape every table or if I can just tweak what I have.

[This is the HTML from the website so you guys can get an idea of what I am doing. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVqRS.png)

> [image]

Comment: You've already figured out how to use `.findAll` to loop over all the table rows and table cells - why not use the same approach to loop over all the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can use `pandas.read_html()` which will read the all tables in nice format.

> Note: it's will return tables as list. so you can access it as `DataFrame` with index such as `print(df[0])` for example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/")

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I second this. If the final goal is to save them via pandas it's better to use pandas from the beginning.

Comment: @rpanai Yes, pretty simple as `df[0].to_csv("data.csv",index= False)`

Comment: OH thank you for this!!! I was told we could use pandas, but the professor didn't teach us so I was a little apprehensive to use them. Question, when I used the code you provided and I go look at the CSV, only the first table is there. Do I need to add more to the code?

Comment: @CarlaMaldonado if you `print(df)` so you will get all as i mentioned above, you can access each table as `DataFrame` once you index it.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη ohhhhh i seee of course. So sorry, yes thank you so much for this!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη, its realy amazing!

Answer (score 2):

*Remove the following*

```
table = all_stock.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt'})
```

*and just use and update*

```
for row in all_stock.find_all('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print(cell.text)
```

---

*Complete code*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/index.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

all_stock = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'wsod_hotStocks'})

for row in all_stock.find_all('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print(cell.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only needed to make a small change to your existing code - use find_all instead of find, and loop through that new iterable.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/index.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

all_stock = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'wsod_hotStocks'})

tables = all_stock.find_all('table',attrs={'class':'wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt'  })

for table in tables:
    print("Next_Table!!")
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
                print(cell.text)
```